# Mac OS X auto Sleep prevention

Tags: macos, macbook, sleep, screensaver

I have a problem with Mac OS X (Leopard) on my MacBook Pro: when I go away for a few minutes my laptop automatically sleeps and all my running applications stop working (such as my downloads). What should I set so that it works like Windows and it shows the lock screen but applications continue doing their job, such as downloading.

P.S.: I downloaded the lock screen widget and when I use it my applications don't close but I lose my internet connection until I unlock my laptop.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Hope you don't mind, but I improved the formatting and the spelling on your question a bit. Good luck with your problem!

Comment: Don't use a widget. Follow the directions in deddebme's answer, then my answer, and when you want to manually lock the screen activate the screen saver with a hot corner (put the mouse cursor in that corner). Done this way, the internet connection is not dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer is based on the OP's comment on deddebme's answer.]

1. Follow deddebme's directions.
2. Go to System Preferences->Desktop & Screen Saver->Screen Saver, then select the screen saver you want and the time you want before it appears. (Optionally, set hot corners for the screen saver as well so you can lock-on-demand.)
3. Go to System Preferences->Security->General, and make sure **Require password to wake this computer from sleep or screen saver** is checked

Now you have everything -- no sleep, auto screen saver with lock, and password required to come back from that. When in screen saver mode, it will continue to have an internet connection.

Comment: Tanx, I hope it work for me :P

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Preference -> Energy Saver, then choose Never to "Put the computer to sleep when it is inactive for".

[image]

Comment: I want it go to lock screen and still have connection to internet

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Jiggler](http://www.sticksoftware.com/software/Jiggler.html) or [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo) to prevent sleeping. Jiggler will wiggle the mouse every 20-60 seconds (depending on settings), InsomniaX will actually prevent sleep even if you close the lid on a laptop.

Comment: +1 for the apps, but please consider adding hyperlinks to the apps. This will make it easier for others to find and learn more about them.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a brilliant little application called [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/)
It resides ind your menu bar as a small coffee cup and when you click it, smoking coffee appears and your Mac will stay completely on. It will even keep the screen from that annoying dimming that makes you touch the mouse every two minutes when wathing youtube.

//Ulrik