# When I lock my screen on my MacBook Pro my running application automatically closes after a while

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, powersave, lock-screen

First I must said that I have been asked this question in different form in [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/51159/mac-os-x-auto-sleep-prevention).
but my problem didn't solved yet.

When I want my laptop do a long schedule thing (like get all Mac OS X new update (need 7 hours)) and I don't want to sit behind it all 7 hours I lock their screen and go away but when I come back and enter password I see that a fresh operating system comes up and no application running!!!

I also use [caffeine](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/caffeine) and set energy saver to ***never*** but still have this problem.

How can I lock my laptop for a long time and my running application work during this time (like you press <kbd>window</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in windows)

I really want a good answer, I don't know can I do it with automator or not?

Comment: You would have been better to expand or reword your original question rather than asking a duplicate.

Comment: there are not exactly the same question, therefor I asked new one.

Comment: How are you locking your screen?

Comment: I use keychain or use hot corner for going to screensaver or my laptop go to lock itself after a while.

Comment: Are you getting logged out or is the machine rebooting? You can type uptime in terminal if you aren't sure.

Comment: it seems I logged out but not restart.